# Can I create an object whose name is written by users?

Tags: c++, object, variables, syntax, naming-conventions

I am new to C++ programming and I need to create an object and name it with a string written on keyboard. However I tried to use pointers and variables, but when I declare an object (let’s say an int) there is no way to give its name after something written by user. I’ll do my best to picture that, forgive me for being so simple.

```
int main() {
 string x;
 std::cin>>x;
 int x;
}
```

I would like to create an int object whose name is the string x previously declared and filled by user on keyboard. However this gives me an error, clearly, and pointers do not seem to work. Is there any other way? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: The real word for the "name" of an object is "identifier". Identifiers are a compile-time concept. It doesn't make sense to consider adding identifiers at runtime. If you want to associate `int`s to `string`s maybe you want `std::map<std::string, int>`. If you show why you want to do this, we could more easily suggest a solution

Comment: *"I need to create an object and name it with a string written on keyboard"* Why do you believe you need to do that? What actual problem do you think it'll help you solve? Describe **that** problem, not your attempted solution. See also: [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Well, you can always wrap it by a struct, have an `int and string` members, store in a vector, and search it by name. But that is pretty much bad and useless.

Comment: `Pointers do not seem to work` Must be a super hard problem if even pointers are useless.

Comment: Unfortunately variable names do not exist in the compiled program, they only exist in the source code. Therefore this problem is impossible. Now whatever bigger problem you are really trying to solve is doable, but this isn't the correct approach.

Comment: Thank you all for giving me advice, I'll try and explain my problem insted of my (wrong thus) approach. To make things clear, I need to let my user create an INT object named ID when he enters a code similar to "INT ID". Thus, when he writes, my program has to split the 2 or more words, and it does, and then recognize which is the type and which the name. So I was thinking about creating a new object of type INT when the system detects the INT word e so on, and wanted to identify that with the 2nd word. In this case, I thought of writing something like INT X in my code, where X is the 2nd word

Answer (score 1):

```
class A{
    public:
    A(){}

    A(std::string _name): name{_name}{}

    void setName(std::string _name)
    {
        name = _name;
    }

    std::string name;
}
```

this is how you object can look like.
you can creat it like this

```
int main()
{
    string x;
    std::cin>>x;
    A a(x); //one option;
    A b;
    b.setName(x);//second option
}
```

Comment: This is not what OP was asking for. He wants to get a variable name from user then associate it with an int.